# How to update the position of my map in Google maps on click?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, android-fragments

Within my application, I have a button that pulls a longitude and latitude from a database and stores them into two variables stored within a class named bgworker, the variables are then displayed on screen as shown here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HF0O.png

I then send the variables to my Google Maps fragment with the code:

```java
 public static void UpdateMap() {
            double Longitute = parseDouble(bgWorker.ReturnLong());
            double Latitude = parseDouble(bgWorker.ReturnLat());
            LatLng Location = new LatLng(Latitude, Longitute);
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Location).title("The location"));
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(Location));
        }
```

However, the map fragment itself never updates and the coordinates are always set to 0,0
How can I update the location on my map whenever the variables are updated (which is on the click of a button)

The two problems I have is, if I make the Googlemap global, the GoogleMap is null and I get the error

```java
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions)' on a null object reference
```

However, if I make the Googlemap local, I cannot pass it from the button within my parent method, or at least, I don't know how to.

The majority of the tutorials I have looked at online deal with updating maps with the users current location, rahter than a static variable.

Please help me update my map location onclick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is within the SO rules but for anyone with the same question in the future, the answer I came to was to store the GoogleMap fragment within the same activity as the button, make the button refresh the whole activity using `startActivity(getIntent());` and then within the googlemap activity, grab the coordinates.

Meaning that every time the googlemap loaded, it grabbed the new coordinates and refreshed itself to the new location! My error was attempting to create a new googlemap every time I pressed the button, you only need one.

Answer (score 0):

I have Idea make your Googlemap local and in onclick pass googleMap in Function so Change your UpdateMap to

```html
public static void UpdateMap(GoogleMap map) {
            double Longitute = parseDouble(bgWorker.ReturnLong());
            double Latitude = parseDouble(bgWorker.ReturnLat());
            LatLng Location = new LatLng(Latitude, Longitute);
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Location).title("The location"));
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(Location));
        }
        
        //and onClickListener Pass Goole Map
        
        
          Your_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              UpdateMap(googleMap)
            }
        });
```

Comment: This doesn't work because the class that has my button doesn't hold any google maps. 
If I make a local googlemap, the same issue crops up as making googlemaps global, it's a null reference object https://i.imgur.com/YVysUQv.png

Comment: have you insert your object GoogleMap true?

Comment: The class which holds the button cannot hold GoogleMaps so I cannot insert one.
If I force the class to hold GoogleMaps in order to insert a GoogleMap I get the error shown above, if I attempt to call the GoogleMap function to create a GoogleMap I get the same error.

Comment: The exact same error as before

https://i.imgur.com/yr8zZ1h.png